# Streaming client-side zip archivation

Tags: javascript, zip, deflate

Is there any JS library that allows to provide input data in chunks rather than expecting 100% file content to be present in memory (string, Buffer, UInt8Array) before starting archivation? I checked several popular libraries like JSZip or archiver and found that they do not offer such functionality.

We process large data tables, client side, using Javascript and we have feature to export table to CSV file, compress and upload to server. Currently we generate huge string which is passed to archiver. What we would ideally want is to have a way to "stream" input and return small chunk of CSV file content (several lines) for archiver library, then return another chunk etc. to avoid using big amount of memory at once.

Comment: Please define "large". Also, it's not massively difficult to send x lines/bytes, then send more once that's done. It really depends on where you're ultimately storing your data. On a database?

Comment: @Lee Taylor, 100+ Mb uncompressed. Splitting into multiple requests or files is also an option, but first I thought to try streaming zip solution

Comment: Also, presumably this is textual data? Why so much data? Where does the browser's data come from? The server?

Comment: @LeeTaylor Yes, that's text data. Data is originated from server, but that is completely separate system from target server that we are sending compressed CSV file. We may do some processing on the client for that data. And also those servers can't talk directly

Comment: Have a look at https://stuk.github.io/jszip/ I think I would start "chunking" your data at the 1MB point and see how you go. You will therefore end up with 100+zip files that you will then need to "join" back together again, but that depends on your needs. It may be that you can compress at bigger chunks (depending on how much they get compressed)

Comment: @LeeTaylor Thank you. Existent solution already uses jszip

Comment: OK. From what I can tell then that's your best bet, chunk it up, zip it, send it to the server and repeat.